# iOS - Pulse animation paused when going to home screen and getting back to the app

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I created a pulse animation using CABasicAnimation, It's working perfectly but my problem is when I go to the home screen or going to another storyboard and getting back to the app or the storyboard that contains the pulse animation the pulse animation is paused, so here is the code I use to make the pulse animation

**CODE:**

```
pbt.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1);
CABasicAnimation *pulsy = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
pulsy.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
pulsy.autoreverses = YES;
pulsy.duration = 0.45;
pulsy.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulsy.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
[pbt.layer addAnimation:pulsy forKey:@"pulseAnimation"];
```

Comment: Used it but the position was changed

Comment: do you want to pause now or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line of code:

```
pulsy.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

So your code will be :

```
pbt.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1);
CABasicAnimation *pulsy = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
pulsy.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
pulsy.autoreverses = YES;
pulsy.duration = 0.45;
pulsy.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulsy.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
pulsy.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[pbt.layer addAnimation:pulsy forKey:@"pulseAnimation"];
```